# Java, Spring Framework MVC - redirection

Tags: java, forms, spring, frameworks

I am using spring framework 3.
I have a form for posting comments to the article. When the form is submitted, it is checked if there any errors.
In case there is no errors, controller returns string

```
"redirect:entryView/"+comment.getEntryId();
```

And everything is okay.

But when there are some errors, if controller returns

```
"redirect:entryView/"+comment.getEntryId();
```

The errors should be displaed near the form with spring-form.tld tags:

```
<form:errors path="author"/>
```

But there are no displayed errors!
When i am trying to return

```
"entryView/"+comment.getEntryId();
```

Without redirect: prefix, then it is going to /rus/WEB-INF/jsp/entryView/8.jsp and there is HTTP Status 404. But it must go to http://example.com/rus/entryView/8, i.e page where the article and form for comments are!

This is view resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

What should i do?

Rest of controller:

```
@Controller
public class CommentController {
private RusService rusService;
private CommentValidator commentValidator;
@Autowired
public CommentController(RusService rusService,CommentValidator commentValidator){
    this.rusService = rusService;
    this.commentValidator = commentValidator;
}
@RequestMapping(value="/addComment",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addComment(Comment comment,BindingResult result){
    commentValidator.validate(comment, result);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "redirect:entryView/"+comment.getEntryId();
    }else{
        rusService.postComment(comment);
        return "redirect:entryView/"+comment.getEntryId();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how is the rest of the controller method defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of errors in `<form:errors path="author"/>` works like this:

- During validation/binding, the `Errors` are saved as an attribute in the `HttpServletResponse` object
- The implementation of this JSP tag calls `response.getAttribute(name)` to find the `Errors` instance to display

When you use `redirect:url`, you are instructing Spring to send a `302 Found` to the client's browser to force the browser to make a *second* request, to the new URL.

Since the redirected-to page is operating with a different set of request/response objects, the original `Errors` is lost.

The simplest way to pass "errors" to a page you want to redirect to in order for the new page to display it would be to handle it yourself, by adding a message to the `Session` object which the second page's controller can look at (or by passing an argument in the URL).

Comment: Hm, but if I change my controller so it returns ModelAndView and type into it: ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();mav.addObject("errors",result.getAllErrors());mav.setViewName("redirect:entryView/"+comment.getEntryId());return mav;       Will it work?

Comment: Did you try it? My point is that by it's very nature sending the client's browser a 302 redirect conflicts with the idea of embedding objects in the response object (which is what the ModelAndView and the Errors object do).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the view of the page of the "add comment" form instead of redirecting to the view that displays the new comment:

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
    return "commentForm";
}
```

You may also have to add `@ModelAttribute Comment` in the method signature...

Answer (score 2):

bkent314 is right:

Have a look at this two method that is a way that defently works.
I separate domain objects from form gui objects (FolderCreateCommand) but that is my style. And in this case I use ModelAndView for return instead of string, because so I have full controll to the model.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "form")
public ModelAndView createForm() {
    return modelAndViewForCreate(new FolderCreateCommand(..default values..));
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid FolderCreateCommand folderCreateCommand,
          BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return modelAndViewForCreate(folderCreateCommand);
    }
    Folder folder = this.folderService.createFolder(folderCreateCommand);
    return redirectToShow(folder);
}


private ModelAndView modelAndViewForCreate(FolderCreateCommand folderCreateCommand) {
    ModelMap uiModel = new ModelMap();
    uiModel.addAttribute("folderCreateCommand", folderCreateCommand);
    uiModel.addAttribute("parentFolders", this.folderDao.readAll());
    return new ModelAndView("folders/create", uiModel);
}

private ModelAndView redirectToShow(Folder folder) {
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/folders/" + folder.getId(), true));
}
```