# form:errors not displaying errors on JSP in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, jsp, render

I want to create simple form which will display errors if input is not proper means if validation fails. I am using spring 3.0 annotations.

I did following things

1 : Created JSP
2 : Created Controller
3 : Created DTO
4 : Created org.springframework.validation.Validator 
    (write an implementation the necessary methods)

int error = bindingResult.getErrorCount() returning the error count and even my page is not being submitted which is expected but my JSP is not showing error messages

I have write  on JSP.

Please guide me how to do this.

If i miss on something please let me know i will paste it.

Comment: How about pasting your source code, jsp, controller, and config files

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780756/java-spring-framework-mvc-redirection/6781509#6781509) for the structure of the controller. The important think is to have a paramter `BindingResult` and if this binding result contains an error you must return the same view (not redirect) again.

In the jsp code you can use the spring errors tag.

@see Spring Reference chapter [16.2.4.14 The errors tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-errorstag) -- there is an example

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this i have just mentioned dto object name in `@ModelAttribute`

```
public void myMethod(@Valid @ModelAttribute**("myDto")** MyDTO myDTO,
        BindingResult bindingResult, ActionResponse response,
        SessionStatus sessionStatus)
```